# Could someone help me resolve my issue reading inputs between files?

Tags: shell-script, shell

There are four files I am using here for this task: an input file, the file whose values I want to change, and two shell scripts. The first file, `models_linearanalysis_Cep.dat` is an input file that is organized as so:

```
1   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4000
2   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4050
3   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4100
4   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4150
5   0.020   0.700   5.4 1500    4200
```

The columns from 1-6 are respectively organized as directory number (`d_number`), Z, X, mass, L, and Teff. I want to use the 6 values from every row to change the assignments of the variables in this second file `inlist_rsp_Cepheid` which has the variables:

```
   RSP_mass = 4.165d0
   RSP_Teff = 6050
   RSP_L = 1438.8d0
   RSP_X = 0.73d0
   RSP_Z = 0.007d0

      log_directory='LOGS_1'
      photo_directory='photos_1'
```

In this instance, the directory number (i.e. the number attached to `LOGS_` and `photos_`) is 1.

In my first shell script, `Inlists_Bash.sh`, shown below I attempt to read values from the six columns of the file `models_linearanalysis_Cep.dat` here, which I intend to read into a second shell script `inlist_changer.sh`.

```
while read -ra fields; do
    for field in "${fields[@]}"; do
        bash inlist_changer.sh <<<"$field"
    done
    ./mk
    ./rn
done < models_linearanalysis_Cep.dat
```

Finally, with the second shell script `inlist_changer.sh`, I use the inputs to finally change the lines in `inlist_rsp_Cepheid` such that the variables have the appropriate values.

```
#!/bin/bash

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12

#used for testing variables
#export mass=4.165d0
#export teff=6050
#export l=1438.8d0
#export x=0.73d0
#export z=0.007d0
#export d_number=2

#read in inputs from the Inlists_Bash.sh file
read -p d_number z x mass l teff 

#inlist directory
export MESA_INLIST="/home/nick/mesa-r11701/star/test_suite/rsp_Cepheid_grid/inlist_rsp_Cepheid"

#change the lines in the MESA_INLIST file
sed -i \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_mass\).*/\1 = $mass/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_Teff\).*/\1 = $teff/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_L\).*/\1 = $l/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_X\).*/\1 = $x/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_Z\).*/\1 = $z/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*log_directory\).*/\1 = 'LOGS_$d_number'/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*photo_directory\).*/\1 = 'photos_$d_number'/i" \
  "$MESA_INLIST"
```

For the first row, I was expecting `inlist_rsp_Cepheid` to look like this:

```
   RSP_mass = 5.4
   RSP_Teff = 4000
   RSP_L = 1500
   RSP_X = 0.700
   RSP_Z = 0.020

      log_directory='LOGS_1'
      photo_directory='photos_1'
```

However, it is clear something is wrong with how I am reading the inputs between these files as I receive this instead:

```
   RSP_mass = 
   RSP_Teff = 
   RSP_L = 
   RSP_X = 
   RSP_Z = 4000

      log_directory='LOGS_'
      photo_directory='photos_'
```

Would someone please explain what I may be missing or doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Since you're new here, please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Inlists_Bash.sh` to this and pass all six values of the array at once to `inlist_changer.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -ra fields; do
  ./inlist_changer.sh "${fields[@]}"
  ./mk
  ./rn
done < models_linearanalysis_Cep.dat
```

---

Change `inlist_changer.sh` to use parameters `$1` ... `$6` instead of using `read`.
The `-p` in `read` is used to print a prompt string (`d_number` in your case) and you were only setting variable `z` in each of your calls.

```
#!/bin/bash

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12
mesa_inlist=/home/nick/mesa-r11701/star/test_suite/rsp_Cepheid_grid/inlist_rsp_Cepheid

sed -i \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_mass\).*/\1 = $4/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_Teff\).*/\1 = $6/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_L\).*/\1 = $5/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_X\).*/\1 = $3/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_Z\).*/\1 = $2/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*log_directory\).*/\1 = 'LOGS_$1'/i" \
  -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*photo_directory\).*/\1 = 'photos_$1'/i" \
  "$mesa_inlist"
```

Note: It's not clear where you need the exported variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

---

Or put everything into one script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=12
mesa_inlist=/home/nick/mesa-r11701/star/test_suite/rsp_Cepheid_grid/inlist_rsp_Cepheid

while read -ra fields; do
  sed -i \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_mass\).*/\1 = ${fields[3]}/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_Teff\).*/\1 = ${fields[5]}/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_L\).*/\1 = ${fields[4]}/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_X\).*/\1 = ${fields[2]}/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*RSP_Z\).*/\1 = ${fields[1]}/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*log_directory\).*/\1 = 'LOGS_${fields[0]}'/i" \
    -e "s/^\([[:blank:]]*photo_directory\).*/\1 = 'photos_${fields[0]}'/i" \
    "$mesa_inlist"
  ./mk
  ./rn
done < models_linearanalysis_Cep.dat
```

Comment: Now, say I want to put all the `LOGS_` and `photos_` into directories: named `LOGS_A`. I  and `photos_A`. I tried to change `LOGS_${fields[0])}` to `LOGS_A/LOGS_${fields[0])}`, but the `LOGS_A` directory is not even created and I get the error `sed: -e expression #6, char 49:unkown option to 's'`. How would you modify the script to do this?

Comment: The `/` is the separator for the substitution (`"s/regexp/replacement/i"`), either escape it as `LOGS_A\/LOGS_${fields[0]}` or change the separator to a different character (`"s#regexp#replacement#i"`).

Comment: One small question. Let's say I don't want to read all the rows in `models_linearanalysis_Cep.dat`, perhaps for example the last 5000 rows. I know that a for loop would be appropriate for this situation, but I am naive about the syntax. Woulf you simply replace `while read -ra fields` with `for read -ra field in fields`?

Comment: You can read the last `N` lines of a file with `tail -nN file` and you could change the 
last line to `done < <(tail -n5000 models_linearanalysis_Cep.dat)` using a process substitution `<(...)`.